# For an automated install of .deb I need to set DPkg::Options before installing package with new conffile

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have a custom Debian package that creates a touch-screen calibration file and will be deployed for automatic updating.  I want to preserve the calibration file if the user has changed it, so my new version of the package has declared this file a "conffile".

The issue is that upon the upgrade to my new version of the package there will be a "conffile" dialog

```
Configuration file `/etc/penmount/penmount.dat'
==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
  What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
  Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
  N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
The default action is to keep your current version.
*** bash.bashrc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I can answer this automatically by creating a /etc/apt/apt.conf/local file with the content:

```
Dpkg::Options {
   "--force-confdef";
   "--force-confold";
}
```

My approach has been to create this local and install it with another package and then use a Pre-Depends to get this package installed before the upgrade of the package with the conffile.

Howver, when I do a dist-upgrade both packages get installed, but the install is halted by  dialog above.  If I install the package that sets the Dpkg options first followed by an install of my "conffile" package the questions are handled automatically.

How to mark an existing configuration file as a conffile and do an automatic update in one pass?

Comment: You can drop files into `/etc/profile.d`. Wouldn't that be simpler than modifying `bash.bashrc`?

Comment: I edited the "conffile" dialog to better match my problem.  It is not related to bashrc issues.